# Loading a dll from another dll in different directories (in an application plugin scenario)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, linker

I'm working on a plugin (lets call it *Cake*) for another application (lets call it *App*). This plugin is written in C++ and produces a dll. On startup, *App* tries to load all dlls from its plugins folder (*PluginDir*). That folder is located at a completely different path than *App's* application folder (*AppDir*). In *PluginDir* I have a shortcut to *Cake* (which is located in the folder *CakeDir*). In summary the structure looks like this:

```
AppDir
  |- App.exe

PluginDir
  |- SomeRandomPlugin1.dll
  |- SomeRandomPlugin2.dll
  |- Cake.dll.lnk

CakeDir
  |- Cake.dll
  |- Dependency.dll
```

In the beginning, *Cake.dll* had no direct dependencies that were linked at load time and everything worked fine. Now I have some dependencies (the contents of *CakeDir*) that are linked at load time and now *Cake* cannot be loaded anymore. I assume it's because the dependency dll are in an unknown search path according to the [dll search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications).

To counteract this, I set the dependency dll up for [delayed loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019) by adding the dependency dll  to *Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Delay Loaded Dlls*. I've also hooked the `DllMain` in order to add *CakeDir* as an additional dll search path:

```
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE const instance, DWORD const reason, LPVOID const /*reserved*/)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("Cake DLL loading...\n");
            const auto pluginDir = getModuleDirectory(instance); // gets CakeDir, also tried to hard code the path, didn't work either
            if (const auto cookie = AddDllDirectory(pluginDir.c_str()))
            {
                g_pluginDirCookie = cookie;
            }
            else
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to register dll search path.\n");
                return FALSE;
            }
            break;
        }
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("Cake DLL unloading...\n");
            RemoveDllDirectory(g_pluginDirCookie);
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The problem is that `DllMain` never gets called and loading *Cake.dll* fails before that (I assume the delayed loading isn't working?).

What am I doing wrong? How can I load my dependencies properly (without having to fall back to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` for every single function)?

Comment: you say : ` in order to add CakeDir as an additional dll search path` you add it as additional libraries path for `AppDir project` or for `PluginDir project` ? Question : `PluginDir` and `CakeDir` is a DLL projects ? or juste folders

Comment: @Landstalker They're all just folders. I have no control over *App* or *AppDir* and neither *PluginDir* (besides adding a shortcut to *Cake.dll*). *CakeDir* is basically the output folder of my Visual Studio Solution.